# How to convert the view into bitmap without adding into the UI in Android

Tags: java, android

I am using View in android and I need to convert this to Bitmap without adding this into the activity.

```
  view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  Bitmap bitmap= view.getDrawingCache();
```

It returns bitmap as null.

Also I have tried the method view.buildDrawingCache() but still getDrawingCache() return null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create empty bitmap and get canvas from it.
use below code for this

```
int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;

Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
```

Now you need to draw you view in this bitmap.
use below code for this

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());

TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
int padding = 4;
textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView.setText("Hello how are you");
layout.addView(textView);
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);

layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
layout.draw(canvas);
```

now your view is converted into the bitmap (bmp).